# Support Arabic in LaTeX .cls file

Tags: fontspec, arabic, documentclass-writing

Can you please add some lines to the following .cls file to support Arabic language?

```
\ProvidesClass{bandar-cv}[2012/04/30 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}


%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors %
%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{999999}

\definecolor{green}{HTML}{C2E15F}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FDA333}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{D3A4F9}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{FB4485}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{6CE0F1}

\ifdefined\@cv@print
  \colorlet{green}{gray}
  \colorlet{orange}{gray}
  \colorlet{purple}{gray}
  \colorlet{brown}{gray}
  \colorlet{red}{gray}
  \colorlet{blue}{gray}
  \colorlet{fillheader}{white}
  \colorlet{header}{gray}
\else
  \colorlet{fillheader}{gray}
  \colorlet{header}{white}
\fi
\colorlet{textcolor}{gray}
\colorlet{headercolor}{gray}

%%%%%%%%%
% Fonts %
%%%%%%%%%
%\RequirePackage[arabic,english]

\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{Helvetica Neue}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{Helvetica Neue UltraLight}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Helvetica Neue Light}

%\setmathfont{XITS Math}

%%%%%%%%%%
% Header %
%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rolefont}{%
  \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\selectfont%
  \thinfont%
  \color{white}%
}

\newcommand{\header}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=4cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
    \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {%
      \fontsize{40pt}{72pt}\color{header}%
      {\thinfont #1}{\bodyfont  #2}
    };
    \node [anchor=north] at (name.south) {%
      \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\color{header}%
      \thinfont #3%
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{2.5cm}
  \vspace{-2\parskip}
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Structure %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{parskip}

\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        blue\or%
        red\or%
        orange\or%
        green\or%
        purple\or%
        brown\else%
        headercolor\fi%
    } #1#2#3%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
  {%
    \LARGE\headingfont\color{headercolor}%
    \@sectioncolor #1%
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
  \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
  {\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} #1}
  \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
}

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}[2]{
  \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
  {\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} #2}
  \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% List environment %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Side block %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\newenvironment{aside}{%
  \let\oldsection\section
  \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} ##1}
  }
  \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)
  \begin{flushright}
  \obeycr
}{%
  \restorecr
  \end{flushright}
  \end{textblock}
  \let\section\oldsection
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[style=verbose, maxnames=99, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{title}{#1\par}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{pages}%
    \newunit%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{note}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{note}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \printfield{type}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \small\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
  \ifblank{#3}{}{#3\space}#1%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma\space}
    {}%
}

\defbibheading{bibheading}[\bibname]{%
   \subsubsection*{#1}
   \markboth{#1}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\printbibsection}[2]{
  \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type={#1}, title={#2}, heading=bibheading]
  \end{refsection}
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{chronological}{
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{year}}
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{month}}
}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Other tweaks %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[left=6.1cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,       
    linkcolor=red,          
    citecolor=red,        
    filecolor=red,      
    urlcolor = red}

% A fix for \href{}{} colors not working with fontspec
\makeatletter
\def\HyColor@@@@UseColor#1\@nil{\addfontfeatures{Color=#1}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: `\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}` to use the arabic font you need `{\arabicfont نص عربي }`

Comment: thanks Salim but in which section to be added. I have tried many solutions but no chance. That's why i included the whole file to mention where could be included.

Comment: After `\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}`, If you are using `xelatex` you need also to add `bidi` package for right to left text

Comment: Can you please extract that section and add it. Regarding bidi , what does it mean and where exactly to add it. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To add arabic in your class you need first an arabic font this can be done with fontspec

```
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
```

You need also macros to change text direction provided by the [`bidi`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bidi)  package, for short right to left text you can use `\RL{arabic text}`, or the environment `RTL` for long text

```
\begin{RTL}
arabic text ......
\end{RTL}
```

---

1. Add arabic font in the class file

   ```
   \ProvidesClass{bandar-cv}[2012/04/30 CV class]
   \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

   \DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
   \DeclareOption*{%
     \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}%
   }
   \ProcessOptions\relax
   \LoadClass{article}


   %%%%%%%%%%
   % Colors %
   %%%%%%%%%%

   \RequirePackage{xcolor}

   \definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

   \definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{333333}
   \definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
   \definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{999999}

   \definecolor{green}{HTML}{C2E15F}
   \definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FDA333}
   \definecolor{purple}{HTML}{D3A4F9}
   \definecolor{red}{HTML}{FB4485}
   \definecolor{blue}{HTML}{6CE0F1}

   \ifdefined\@cv@print
     \colorlet{green}{gray}
     \colorlet{orange}{gray}
     \colorlet{purple}{gray}
     \colorlet{brown}{gray}
     \colorlet{red}{gray}
     \colorlet{blue}{gray}
     \colorlet{fillheader}{white}
     \colorlet{header}{gray}
   \else
     \colorlet{fillheader}{gray}
     \colorlet{header}{white}
   \fi
   \colorlet{textcolor}{gray}
   \colorlet{headercolor}{gray}

   %%%%%%%%%
   % Fonts %
   %%%%%%%%%
   %\RequirePackage[arabic,english]

   \RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
   \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri} % <-- add arabic font 
   \RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}

   \newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{Helvetica Neue}
   \newfontfamily\thinfont[]{Helvetica Neue UltraLight}
   \newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold}

   \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
   \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Helvetica Neue Light}

   %\setmathfont{XITS Math}

   %%%%%%%%%%
   % Header %
   %%%%%%%%%%

   \RequirePackage{tikz}

   \newcommand{\rolefont}{%
     \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\selectfont%
     \thinfont%
     \color{white}%
   }

   \newcommand{\header}[3]{%
     \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
       \node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum 
   width=\paperwidth, minimum height=4cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
       \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {%
         \fontsize{40pt}{72pt}\color{header}%
         {\thinfont #1}{\bodyfont  #2}
       };
       \node [anchor=north] at (name.south) {%
         \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\color{header}%
         \thinfont #3%
       };
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \vspace{2.5cm}
     \vspace{-2\parskip}
   }


   %%%%%%%%%%%%%
   % Structure %
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \RequirePackage{parskip}

   \newcounter{colorCounter}
   \def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
     {%
       \color{%
         \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
           blue\or%
           red\or%
           orange\or%
           green\or%
           purple\or%
           brown\else%
           headercolor\fi%
       } #1#2#3%
     }%
     \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
   }

   \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
     \par\vspace{\parskip}
     {%
       \LARGE\headingfont\color{headercolor}%
       \@sectioncolor #1%
     }
     \par\vspace{\parskip}
   }

   \renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
     \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
     {\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} #1}
     \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
   }

   \renewcommand{\subsubsection}[2]{
     \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
     {\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} #2}
     \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
   }

   \pagestyle{empty}


   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   % List environment %
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

   \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
   \newenvironment{entrylist}{%
     \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
   }{%
     \end{tabular*}
   }
   \renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
   \newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
     #1&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
       \textbf{#2}%
       \hfill%
       {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
       #4\vspace{\parsep}%
     }\\}


   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   % Side block %
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%

   \RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
   \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
   \setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
   \newenvironment{aside}{%
     \let\oldsection\section
     \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
       \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} ##1}
     }
     \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)
     \begin{flushright}
     \obeycr
   }{%
     \restorecr
     \end{flushright}
     \end{textblock}
     \let\section\oldsection
   }

   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   % Bibliography %
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

   \RequirePackage[style=verbose, maxnames=99, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

   \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\par}
   \DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1\par}
   \DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{#1\par}
   \DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1\par}
   \DeclareFieldFormat[report]{title}{#1\par}

   \DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
     \printfield{title}%
     \newblock%
     \printnames{author}%
     \par%
     \newblock%
     {%
       \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
       \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
       \setunit{\space}%
       \printfield{pages}%
       \newunit%
       \printlist{publisher}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{year}%
       \newunit%
     }
     \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
   }

   \DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
     \printfield{title}%
     \newblock%
     \printnames{author}%
     \par%
     \newblock%
     {%
       \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
       \printlist{publisher}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{note}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{year}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printlist{location}%
       \newunit%
     }
     \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
   }


   \DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
     \printfield{title}%
     \newblock%
     \printnames{author}%
     \par%
     \newblock%
     {%
       \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
       \printfield{booktitle}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{year}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printlist{location}%
       \newunit%
     }
     \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
   }

   \DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}{%
     \printfield{title}%
     \newblock%
     \printnames{author}%
     \par%
     \newblock%
     {%
       \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
       \printfield{booktitle}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{note}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{year}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printlist{location}%
       \newunit%
     }
     \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
   }

   \DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}{%
     \printfield{title}%
     \newblock%
     \promma\space}
       {}%
   }

   \defbibheading{bibheading}[\bibname]{%
      \subsubsection*{#1}
      \markboth{#1}{#1}
   }

   \newcommand{\printbibsection}[2]{
     \begin{refsection}
       \nocite{*}
       \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type={#1}, title={#2}, 
    heading=bibheading]
     \end{refsection}
   }

   \DeclareSortingScheme{chronological}{
     \sort[direction=descending]{\field{year}}
     \sort[direction=descending]{\field{month}}
   }



   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   % Other tweaks %
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

   \RequirePackage[left=6.1cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,nohead,nofoot] 
   {geometry}
   \RequirePackage{hyperref}
   \hypersetup{
       colorlinks=false,       
       linkcolor=red,          
       citecolor=red,        
       filecolor=red,      
       urlcolor = red}

   % A fix for \href{}{} colors not working with fontspec
   \makeatletter
   \def\HyColor@@@@UseColor#1\@nil{\addfontfeatures{Color=#1}}
   \makeatother
   ```
2. Add `bidi` package in  your tex file for right to left writing  ( bidi should be the last package that you load)

   ```
   \documentclass{bandar-cv}
   % add your packages here 
   \usepackage{bidi}

   \begin{document}

   % write short arabic text with 
   \RL{\arabicfont   نص عربي قصير}

   % write long arabic text with 

   \begin{RTL}
   \arabicfont
   نص عربي طويل به العديد من الأسطر 
   ........
   ........ 
   \end{RTL} 

   \end{document}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use `polyglossia` and Arabic numerals (I don't know why one would use Latin numerals and months in Arabic, you can see the difference below):

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setotherlanguage[locale=mashriq]{arabic} %locale=maghrib (default) 
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Amiri} % <-- add arabic font % add your packages here  \usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}

% write short arabic text with  \RL{\arabicfont   نص عربي قصير}

% write long arabic text with 

\begin{RTL} \arabicfont 123456789 نص عربي طويل به العديد من الأسطر  ........ ........  \today  \end{RTL} 

\begin{Arabic} 123456789 نص عربي طويل به العديد من الأسطر 

\today \end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

[image: arabic and polyglossia]

Change `\usepackage` to `\RequirePackage` in your `.cls` file and you're ready to go.